# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity couldn't find ApplicationUser

Tags: .net, authentication, identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I've included Identity into my .NET Core2.1 project, when I try to build the project, it warns me with the following error:

The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' couldn't be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Should I define ApplicationUser myself or Identity will create it by itself?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to  create the ApplicationUser class yourself. The default user is IdentityUser. ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

But if you are not extending ApplicationUser then you can also use IdentityUser. So instead of this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

you can use this:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
```

And replace ApplicationUser throughout the rest of the project with IdentityUser.

Comment: From Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-user-data